# Nhibernate vb.net mvc could not compile mapping

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, nhibernate, model-view-controller

i'm new to NhIbernate and Vb.net MVC, i'm trying to do this Tutorial. I'm using VS 2013

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/09/asp-net-mvc-nhibernate-crud-getting-started.html

But using Vb.net instead of C#
My current configuration is that

[image]

I'm getting those exception:

```
{"Could not compile the mapping document: d:\documenti\visual studio 2013\Projects\NhibernateMVC\NhibernateMVC\Models\Nhibernate\Employee.hbm.xml"}

{"persistent class NhibernateMVC.Models.Employee, NhibernateMVC not found"}

{"Impossibile caricare il tipo 'NhibernateMVC.Models.Employee' dall'assembly 'NhibernateMVC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"NhibernateMVC.Models.Employee"}
```

This is my Employee.vb class

```
Namespace NhibernateMVC.Models
    Public Class Employee

        Public _Id As Integer = 0
        Public _FirstName As String = ""
        Public _LastName As String = ""
        Public _Designation As String = ""

        Public Overridable Property Id() As Integer
            Get
                Return _Id
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
                _Id = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overridable Property FirstName() As String
            Get
                Return _FirstName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                _FirstName = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overridable Property LastName() As String
            Get
                Return _LastName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                _LastName = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overridable Property Designation() As String
            Get
                Return _Designation
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                _Designation = Value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Namespace
```

This my Employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="NhibernateMVC" namespace="NhibernateMVC.Models">
      <class name="Employee" table="Employee" dynamic-update="true" >
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
          <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="FirstName" />
        <property name="LastName" />
        <property name="Designation" />
      </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this one, the NHIbernateSession.vb

```
Imports System.Web
Imports NHibernate
Imports NHibernate.Cfg

Namespace NhibernateMVC.Models

    Public Class NHibertnateSession
        Public Shared Function OpenSession() As ISession
            Dim configuration As New Configuration()

            Dim configurationPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\Models\Nhibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml")
            Dim employeeConfigurationFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\Models\Nhibernate\Employee.hbm.xml")

            configuration.Configure(configurationPath)

            configuration.AddFile(employeeConfigurationFile)
            Dim sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory()

            Return sessionFactory.OpenSession()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: I think you added your hibernate.cfg.xml file instead of the mapping file. Could you show the mapping file?

Comment: sure! i'm going editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET has the concept of *root namespaces*. Basically, the root namespace is prepended to any namespaces you declare with `Namespace`.

What this means is in your `Employee` class when you defined the namespace:

```
Namespace NhibernateMVC.Models
```

Because of the root namespace of the project (which is probably `NhibernateMVC` unless you've changed it), the fully qualified name of the class is actually `NhibernateMVC.NhibernateMVC.Models.Employee`.

You can do a few things to fix the problem:

1. Remove the *Root Namespace* from *Project Properties*.
2. Change the namespace of the `Employee` class:

   ```
   Namespace Models
   ```
3. Change your Employee.hbm.xml file to point to the correct fully-qualified name:

   ```xml
   <hibernate-mapping
       xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
       auto-import="true"
       assembly="NhibernateMVC"
       namespace="NhibernateMVC.NhibernateMVC.Models">
   ```

I'd personally go with #2 since the others are confusing. Once you make that change, you'll run into another problem--NHibernate doesn't like that you have public backing fields for your properties. You should tweak your `Employee` class to use `Private` backing fields instead:

```
Namespace Models
    Public Class Employee

        Private _Id As Integer = 0
        Private _FirstName As String = ""
        Private _LastName As String = ""
        Private _Designation As String = ""
   ' ... etc
```

A side-note: the class `NHibertnateSession` has a typo in its name (this is present in the tutorial as well). It should probably be `NHibernateSession` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution, i've followed the second step, and i've solved, the class attributes was a lapse during the trying!